# Unable to view rich:panel

Tags: eclipse, jsf, richfaces

I am new to JSF and richfaces. I have created a AddEmployee.xhtml which includes rich:panels, rich:dropDownMenu and rich:toolbar. This xhtml is part of my application. In runtime when I reach it from other page I able to see it's contents but couldn't see the rich:panel (Panel border). But when I run this AddEmployee.xhtml directly as 'Run in server' I can view this panel. My question is why I unable to see this panel layout when I reach the page from other page ??

I am use Eclipse IDE (juno).
Jars I am using are..

```
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar, commons-codec-1.3.jar, commons-collections-3.2.jar, commons-configuration-1.0.jar, commons-diagester-1.8.jar, commons-discovery-0.4.jar, 
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, jsf-api-2.1.7.jar, jsf-impl-2.1.7.jar, jstl.jar,
```

cssparser-0.9.5.jar, guava-11.0.rc1.jar, richfaces-components-api.4.3.2.Final.jar
richfaces-components-ui-4.3.2.Final.jar, richfaces-core-api-4.3.2.Final.jar, richfaces-core-impl-4.3.2.Final.jar, sac-1.3.jar

### Faces.config.xml

```
<faces-config
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<managed-bean>
<managed-bean-name>MenuBean</managed-bean-name>
<managed-bean-class>org.com.bean.MenuBean</managed-bean-class>
<managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>UserLogin</managed-bean-name>
<managed-bean-class>org.com.bean.UserLogin</managed-bean-class>
<managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
<managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>EmployeeMaster</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>org.com.bean.EmployeeMaster</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
<navigation-case>
    <from-action>#{MenuBean.addEmployee}</from-action>
    <from-outcome>AddEmployee</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/employee/AddEmployee.xhtml</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
</faces-config>
```

### Header.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">


<rich:toolbar height="46px">
        <rich:dropDownMenu mode="ajax" verticalOffset="1">
            <f:facet name="label">
                <h:outputText value="Home"/>
            </f:facet>
    <rich:menuItem label="Home" action="#{MenuBean.showHome}"></rich:menuItem>
        </rich:dropDownMenu>
        <rich:dropDownMenu mode="ajax">
            <f:facet name="label" >
                <h:outputText value="Employee"/>
            </f:facet>
      <rich:menuItem label="AddEmployee" action="#{MenuBean.addEmployee}">
      </rich:menuItem>
<rich:menuItem label="EmployeeDetails" action="#MenuBean.showEmployeeDetails}"/>
<rich:menuItem label="TerminateEmployee" action="#{MenuBean.terminateEmployee}"/>
<rich:menuItem label="UpdateEmployee" action="#{MenuBean.updateEmployee}"/>
        </rich:dropDownMenu>
    </rich:toolbar>
 </ui:composition>
```

### Login.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <title> Login </title>
</h:head>

<body>
<h:form>
<center>
<rich:panel header="Login" style="text-align:left;font-style:normal;               text-decoration:none;width : 343px; height : 181px; color: Black;">
    <center>

        <h:outputText value="Username"/> &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;
<h:inputText id="username" value="#{UserLogin.userName}" required="true"/>
            <h:outputText value="&lt;br/&gt;" escape="false" />
            <h:outputText value="&lt;br/&gt;" escape="false" />
        <h:outputText value="Password"/>  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;
<h:inputText id="password" value="#{UserLogin.userPwd}" required="true"/>
            <h:outputText value="&lt;br/&gt;" escape="false" />
            <h:outputText value="&lt;br/&gt;" escape="false" />

        <h:commandButton value="Login"
                    action="#{UserLogin.login}" />   &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <h:commandButton type="reset" value="reset"/> 

    </center>
</rich:panel>
</center>
</h:form>
</body>
</ui:composition>
```

### AddEmployee.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <title> Add new employee </title>
</h:head>

<body>
<h:form>

    <ui:insert name="CommonHeader">
        <ui:include src="/Header.xhtml"></ui:include>
    </ui:insert>    

<!-- Header definition over -->
        <br></br>
        <table align="left" cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="5">
          <tr><td> 
          <rich:panel header="Employee Primary Details" style="text-align:left;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;width : 350px; height : 200px;" rendered="true">

            <h:outputText value="Enter User name : "  style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold;"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;     
            <h:inputText id="empIde" value="#{EmployeeMaster.empId}" />

            <br/><br/>

            <h:outputText value="Enter firstname : " style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold;"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <h:inputText id="firstNamee" value="#{EmployeeMaster.firstName}" />
            <br/><br/>

            <h:outputText value="Enter lastName : " style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold;"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <h:inputText id="lastNamee" value="#{EmployeeMaster.lastName}"  />
            <br/><br/>

            <h:outputText value="Person Type :"  style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold;"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <h:selectOneMenu id ="personType" value="#{EmployeeDetailBean.personType}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="ASE-T" itemLabel="ASE-T" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="BA" itemLabel="BA" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="Business Associate" itemLabel="Business Associate" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="Employee" itemLabel="Employee" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <br/><br/>

        </rich:panel>           
    </td></tr></table></h:form> </body> </html>
```

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>roaster1</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
  <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
  <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
  <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
<param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>
 <listener>
   <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.com.init.Listener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

When I edit the source of both XHTML I found the following is missing from the one ...

```
<link href="/roaster2/faces/rfRes/panel.ecss?db=eAHjW!XqPQAE!QKS&ln=org.richfaces" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
 <script src="/roaster2/faces/javax.faces.resource/json-dom.js?ln=org.richfaces" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/roaster2/faces/javax.faces.resource/jquery.effects.core.js?ln=org.richfaces" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/roaster2/faces/javax.faces.resource/jquery.effects.highlight.js?ln=org.richfaces" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/roaster2/faces/javax.faces.resource/JQuerySpinBtn.js?ln=org.richfaces" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/roaster2/faces/javax.faces.resource/calendar-utils.js?ln=org.richfaces" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/roaster2/faces/javax.faces.resource/calendar.js?ln=org.richfaces" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <link href="/roaster2/faces/rfRes/calendar.ecss?db=eAHjW!XqPQAE!QKS&ln=org.richfaces" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
```

Comment: Could you try reducing the code you've posted to a more minimal example that demonstrates your issue? It will make it easier for others to help you, and you may discover the solution on your own in the process.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases, your best help are tools like web inspectors. In Firefox you can use Firebug (plugin) or "Right click over the element -> Inspect element". Chrome also contains tools like that. These tools allow you check all web elements (DOM tree, CSS, JavaScript, etc.), so you can check wich HTML or CSS properties your have in any element at any time.

A possible solution to your matter, is that the border of panel when you include them in other page, is hidden by the border of the container where the component is.

I hope this answer help you,

Regards,